# Getting Email address from Polymer firebase-auth element with Google Authentication

Tags: firebase, polymer, firebase-security, firebasesimplelogin

Using Firebase Auth I want to get the email address from a Google login so I need the scope email. How can I add that to the firebase-auth element? Is it in params? If so, how? An example would be great.

To help one of my devs created a Polymer Element which has the login

https://github.com/HackITtoday/hi9-login/blob/master/hi9-login.html

Thanks

Comment: Cross post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/HcH76SxUESQ

Comment: Could you show us some code you have so far?

Comment: I have added the link to the element with the code in. Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done by calling one of `<firebase-auth>`'s *less* public APIs.

```
<firebase-auth
    id="auth"
    provider="{{provider}}"
    app-name="[[appName]]"
    signed-in="{{signedIn}}"
    user="{{user}}"
    on-error="onAuthError"></firebase-auth>
```

Inside an element's Polymer definition...

```
// Currently supported providers are 'google', 'facebook', 'github', 'twitter'
loginUsingProvider: function(name) {
    var provider = this.$.auth._providerFromName(name);
    // Twitter simple login doesn't have scopes.
    if (name != 'twitter') {
        provider.addScope('email');
    }
    this.$.auth.signInWithPopup(provider)
        .then(function(response) {
            // success
        }, function(error) {
            // failure
        })
        .catch(function(exception) {
            // Exception 
        });
}
```

This was done using `polymerfire` version 0.9.4. Check your versions by using `bower install polymerfire`).

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs [here](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/firebase-element?active=firebase-auth) there is a property that is an Object called `user` which:

> When logged in, this property reflects the firebase user auth object.

This should contain the information you require.

Comment: You would think so but it doesn't. It seems to miss the scope email.

Comment: I am running into the same issue and it looks like we'll have to use the non-polymer JS methods of authenticating to add scopes. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/polymer-firebase-pwa/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#17) codelab which may help